# Adding seconds in a date parameter - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

In an SSRS report I have an end date parameter that, by using this expression:

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

defaults to the last day of the previous month when my users run the report.

However I'd like the expression to also show seconds so that its output would be (this uses UK time):

30/09/2019 23:59:59

I have got round this by using:

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0)).ADDSECONDS(+86399)
```

But I was wondering if there were a simpler, dare I say more *elegant* expression I could use to achieve what it is I'm after? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, from my perspective, you might have as elegant an answer as you'll get.  The only other thing I could think of could be to get the `dateadd` to select the first day of the current month and `.ADDSECONDS(-1)`.  Something like `=DateAdd("d",-(Day(today)-1), Today).AddSeconds(-1)`. Or `=DateSerial(year(Today), Month(Today), 1).AddSeconds(-1)`. Doesn't really do a ton to shorten things, but makes it a little less clunky than adding 86399 seconds.

Comment: Yes good idea - thanks for taking the trouble to get back.